# Rotate and Translate UIImageView with NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, nstimer, cgaffinetransform

So I'm working on a quick animation of a car and I want the tires to rotate and translate forward... but for some reason they were sliding forward but then I added the code to rotate them and now they rotate and jump random x positions back and forth, it's super confusing and I have NO clue what's happening.. did I leave out a required framework or something?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    frame = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/40.f
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(enterFrame)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];


}


-(void)enterFrame {

    //spin += +0.5;
    spin = 0.5;

    //wheel.center = CGPointMake(wheel.center.x+0.5, wheel.center.y);
    wheel.center = CGPointMake(wheel.center.x+spin, wheel.center.y);

    //wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(spin);        
    wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(wheel.transform, spin);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To rotate around an arbitrary point (i.e. not the origin):**

1. shift the origin to the arbitrary point
2. perform rotation.
3. shift the origin back to original location.

(following link points to the math involved : http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/aroundPoint/matrix2d/)

**Try the following code, this might solve your problem:**

```
//translate the origin to the center of the wheel                                           
wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, wheel.center.x, wheel.center.y);   

//rotate the wheel
wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(wheel.transform, spin);   

//translate the origin back
wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(wheel.transform,-wheel.center.x,-wheel.center.y);  

//Move the wheel 
wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(wheel.transform,wheel.center.x+spin, wheel.center.y);
```

Comment: This allows it to spin around a given point, but I still can't make the object move on any given run through of the NSTimer thread. If I put your code down then I put moving code like `wheel.center = CGPointMake` and try to slide it over 5 pixels to the right every frame, it does not move, it only spins. I appreciate the rotation code though +1

Comment: Updated the code to apply a translate on the transform. This should move the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the angle irrespective of its current transformation like:

```
wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( spin/180*M_PI );
```

Comment: You were not converting **spin** (degree) into radians like 'spin/180*M_PI`. Did you?

Comment: I have done it with doing that and also without doing that. I didn't notice any difference, the glitch still occurred. It shouldn't matter anyways because whatever number I put in there is some form of a radian.

Comment: Try decreasing the timer value like 1/20.0f. May be the method is being called again before the previous transformation ends.